# Fail to make good approximation with a Taylor Series

Tags: series-expansion, approximation

I am trying to approximate the following expression for values of $m$ close to 0 and for values large values of $Ne$ ($m$ is bounded between 0 and 1 and $Ne$ is a positive integer)

$$X=-\frac{(m-1)^2}{2 m^2 \text{Ne}-m^2-4 m \text{Ne}+2 m-1}$$

I tried

```
Normal[Series[-((-1 + m)^2/(-1 + 2 m - m^2 - 4 m Ne + 2 m^2 Ne)), {m, 
   0, 1}]]
```

and also

```
Normal[Series[-((-1 + m)^2/(-1 + 2 m - m^2 - 4 m Ne + 
      2 m^2 Ne)) /. {m -> a/Ne}, {a, 0, 1}]] /. {a -> m Ne}
```

and both returned

$$1-4 m Ne$$

However $1-4 m Ne$ is actually a very poor approximation. The approximation of this expression is a classic result in population genetics. The approximation I am trying to reach is $\frac{1}{1+4 m Ne}$. $\frac{1}{1+4 m Ne}$ is indeed a good approximation as seen visually

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[{1 - 4 m Ne, 1/(
   1 + 4 Ne m), -((-1 + m)^2/(-1 + 2 m - m^2 - 4 m Ne + 
     2 m^2 Ne))}, {m, 0, 0.1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 0.1} {0, 0.1}}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Green, Red, Black}], {Ne, 1*^3, 1*^4}]
```

[image]

red line is $\frac{1}{1+4 m Ne}$, green is $1-4 m Ne$ (that returns negative values for most of the range of $m$ values) and the black line is the function that I am trying to approximate.

**Can you help me to approximate this expression?**

Comment: I gave a computational way to arrive at the result in my answer, but I'm curious, why not just type `1/(1 + 4 m Ne)`?

Comment: because, I am trying to learn to make approximations. I did not know about Pade approximation technic. You say it is a "computational way", but it is not a numerical approximation (but an analytical one), right?

Comment: By "computational" I meant computed (analytically) from the function by *Mathematica*, instead of typing out the expression based on math knowledge that you personally have.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps this?

```
PadeApproximant[-((-1 + m)^2/(-1 + 2 m - m^2 - 4 m Ne + 2 m^2 Ne)), {m, 0, {0, 1}}]
(*  1/(1 + 4 m Ne)  *)
```

Note: A Taylor series is a power series, so one cannot hope for a rational approximation in the form sought.  Note also that `1 - 4 m Ne` is the Taylor series approximant to the Padé approximant above.

Comment: I did not know about Pade approximation technic. Thanks +1. I don't know how you made the decision about the orders in the numerator and denominator but I suppose I'll have to further my understanding of Pade approximation to understand that, right?

Comment: @Remi.b Since the degrees of `m` in the numerator/denominator of the desired solution are 0/1 respectively, `{0, 1}` seems like the best thing to try first, yes? [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padé_approximant) gives a pretty good summary of Padé approximation.

Answer (score 3):

If you inverse the given function, and inverse it's Taylor approximation, you would achieve a better approximation. it seems that the extreme changes around zero makes it unsuitable for Taylor expansion.

```
1/Normal[Simplify@Series[1/-((-1 + m)^2/(-1 + 2 m - m^2 - 4 m Ne + 2 m^2 Ne)), {m, 0,1}]] 

    (* 1/(1+4 m Ne)*)
```

Here is the verification of first order and second order approximations derived by this technique:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[{-((-1 + m)^2/(-1 + 2 m - m^2 - 4 m Ne + 2 m^2 Ne)), 1/(
   1 + 4 m Ne), 1/(1 + 4 m Ne + 6 m^2 Ne)}, {m, 0, 0.1}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 0.1} {0, 0.1}}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Green, Red, Black}], {Ne, 1*^3, 1*^4}]
```

[image]